# not able to loop through a blessed object

Tags: perl

I have an array that results in the following variable with blessed objects inside it. How do I iterate through it to get the name of each variable?

```
$VAR1 = [
  bless( {
    'name' => 'apple',
    'address' => 'kashmir'
  }),
  bless( {
    'name' => 'mango',
    'address' => 'chicago'
  })
];

$VAR1 = bless( {
  'name' => 'grape',
  'address' => 'amsterdam'
});
```

Comment: This code looks odd. Usually `bless` is for instantiating an object, which implies a class. I'm not quite sure why it's being used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[...]` indicate that `$VAR1` is an array reference, which you dereference with `@$VAR1`.  (Replacing `VAR1` with the actual name of the variable, of course.  Data::Dumper can't see the actual variable names, so it turns them all into `VAR1`.)  Once you've dereferenced, you can treat it like a normal array, looping over it, `push`ing, `shift`ing, etc.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $VAR1 = [
  bless( {
    'name' => 'apple',
    'address' => 'kashmir'
  }),
  bless( {
    'name' => 'mango',
    'address' => 'chicago'
  })
];

for my $item (@$VAR1) {
  say $item->{name};
}
```

Output:

```
apple
mango
```

Comment: I actually tried this but it didn't work saying 'Not an ARRAY reference'

Comment: You can use Data::Dumper to see what is really inside the variable. See `perldoc Data::Dumper`, http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html